# O que é uma entidade?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, ddd, princípios-de-programação

Usa-se o termo Entidade em alguns contextos de desenvolvimento de software.

Refere-se em geral a um objeto, geralmente do modelo de domínio, que pode ser persistido em banco de dados, como um Item de Pedido, um Produto, etc.

Algumas tecnologias caracterizam o termo de maneira mais específica. Entidades em tecnologias de persistência/ORMs como JPA/Hibernate, EJBs, Entity Framework, etc.

Também é usado em modelagem conceitual e em DDD (*Domain-Driven Design*).

O que é exatamente uma entidade e o que a diferencia de outros tipos de objetos?

Coloquei algumas tags, peço que revisem pois não sei se todas se aplicam, ou se outras podem ser aplicadas.

Comment: Cheguei à conclusão que é só a definição do dicionário mesmo, referindo-se à coisa concreta representada por um objeto que você queira eventualmente persistir em banco. Então você, eu, uma cidade, somos todos entidades. Não há, em princípio, nenhum significado computacional adicional para o termo.

Comment: Entidade é o que está atrás de você agora 

Comment: @CypherPotato Entidade é o Exu-Bugginho que vai baixar no seu código já já pelas próximas três  gerações :D